# String.split() from strtok

Tags: c

I would like to create a variable-length array of pointers to do a string split. For example, something like:

```
>>> s="Hello my name is Sam".split()
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Sam']
```

I have a general way to print them currently:

```
int main() {

    char _string[] = "Hello my name is Sam";
    char * string = _string;

    char * token;
    char * delim = " ";
    token = strtok(string, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}
```

How could I create a variable-length array of string-pointers? My first thought was just to choose a big number, but that doesn't seem like the best idea.

Additionally, is there a better pattern than using:

```
char _string[] = "Hello my name is Sam";
char * string = _string;
```

I feel like I do this so frequently, and if I do it the "normal" way (i.e., the way that feels most normal to me as a beginner):

```
char * string = "Hello my name is Sam";
```

I'll always get some `Bus Error` down the road or something. How should this be properly done?

Comment: Do you have the option of using C++? If so, a vector could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @kmort nope, I'm trying to learn C first.

Comment: `char string[] = "Hello my name is Sam";`; if you try to use that array as a pointer, it’ll become a pointer.

Comment: Well then, it seems as if you're going to be rolling your own collection, or using someone's straight C collection library. I always hesitate to do something like that, as it really is a solved problem. But, if you must, here's something I found: https://github.com/srdja/Collections-C/tree/master/src   And, bravo for learning C. :-)

Comment: In your code you will get bus errors or similar because `strtok` will modify the string you pass and you pass a string literal which is readonly.

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for that note. How should it be passed instead so I don't get the bus error?

Comment: @Shared simply drop 'string' and use '_string' instead. What is the purpose to add an extra pointer instead  using the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to count the number of tokens first, then allocate dynamically memory for a list and then fill the list.

In code it could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_tokens(char *str, char *delim) {
    if(str == NULL || strlen(str) == 0)
        return 0;
    int number = 0;
    char *p = str, *prev = str;
    while((p = strpbrk(p, delim)) != NULL) {
        if(p != prev)
            number++;
        prev = ++p;
    }
    if(strlen(prev) != 0)
        number++;
    return number;
}


int main() {
    char string[] = "Hello my name is Sam";
    char *delim = " ";

    int num_tokens = count_tokens(string, delim);
    char **token_list = calloc(num_tokens, sizeof(char *));

    char *token = strtok(string, delim);
    for(int i = 0; i < num_tokens && token != NULL; i++) {
        token_list[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num_tokens; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", token_list[i]);
    }

    free(token_list);
}
```

Comment: You can simply `realloc` pointers when you run out and do the split in a single pass through `string`.

Comment: The code will fail if ran with an "emtpy" string (`""`) as input.

Comment: 1) Code is broken (UB) when `string` begins or ends with a space (or is empty) - attempts to print `NULL`.  2) better to use `size_t` than `int` for delimiter count.

Comment: "How should this be properly done?" --> Answer fails (UB)  when `char * string = "Hello my name is Sam";` instead of `char string[] = "Hello my name is Sam";`  Could use `strspn(), strcspn()` instead of `strtok()` to remedy

Comment: strtok replaces the delimiters with NULL to tokenize the string so that a writable string is required instead of a string literal. The part of the question I understood as how to do this without the need to write an additional statement to assign the array to an additional char* variable. Therefore the answer is using a writable char array and the fact this array decays to a char *.

Comment: Good points. I have updated my answer to correctly also handle input with empty string or with leading or trailing delimiters, or even using multiple successive delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Another, a more flexible approach is to dynamically extend the target variable if necessary:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

const size_t size_delta = 2; /* Adust to any value > 0 */

int string_to_tokens(char * s, const char * delimiters, char *** pptoken)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */
  int errno_saved = 0;

  if (NULL == s || NULL == pptoken)
  {
    /* Invalid input */
    result = -1;
    errno_saved = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    size_t tokens = 0;
    size_t size = 1;

    *pptoken = malloc(size * sizeof **pptoken);
    if (NULL == *pptoken)
    {
      errno_saved = errno;
      result = -1;
    }
    else
    {
      (*pptoken)[tokens] = strtok(s, delimiters);

      while (NULL != (*pptoken)[tokens])
      {
        ++tokens;
        if (tokens >= size)
        {
          size += size_delta;

          {
            void * pv = realloc(*pptoken, size * sizeof **pptoken);
            if (NULL == pv)
            {
              errno_saved = errno;
              result = -1;
              break;
            } 

            *pptoken = pv;
          }
        }
        char * pc = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
        (*pptoken)[tokens] = pc;
      }
    }

    if (0 != errno_saved)
    {
      free(*pptoken);
      errno = errno_saved;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

The draw back with above solution is that

- it modifies the content of the source array `s` by placing a `'\0'` every where a delimiter was found.
- the resulting pointer array's elements refer to the source array

To work around this just make sure you code does not care(;-)), or extend the tokeniser to 1st create a working copy and as well duplicate the tokens found:

```
int string_to_tokens_nondistructive(const char * s, const char * delimiters, char *** pptoken)
{
  int result = 0; /* Be optimistic. */

  if (NULL == s || NULL == pptoken)
  {
    /* Invalid input */
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    int errno_saved = 0;
    char * w = strdup(s);

    if (NULL == w)
    {
      errno_saved = errno;
      result = 01;
    }
    else
    {
      size_t tokens = 0;
      size_t size = 1;
      *pptoken = malloc(size * sizeof **pptoken);

      char * p = strtok(w, delimiters);

      while (NULL != p)
      {
        (*pptoken)[tokens] = strdup(p);
        if (NULL == (*pptoken)[tokens])
        {
          errno_saved = errno;
          result = -1;
          break;
        } 

        ++tokens;

        if (tokens >= size)
        {
          size += size_delta;

          {
            void * pv = realloc(*pptoken, size * sizeof **pptoken);
            if (NULL == pv)
            {
              errno_saved = errno;
              result = -1;
              break;
            } 

            *pptoken = pv;
          }
        }

        p = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
      }

      (*pptoken)[tokens] = NULL;

      free(w);
    }

    if (0 != errno_saved)
    {
      free(*pptoken);
      errno = errno_saved;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use them like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int string_to_tokens(char * s, const char * delimiters, char *** pptoken);

void print_tokens(char * const * ptoken)
{
  char * const * p = ptoken;
  while (NULL != *p)
  {
    puts(*p);
    ++p;
  }
}

void hexdump_chararray(const char * a, size_t s)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i < s)
  {
    printf("%02hhx ", a[i]);
    ++i;
    if (0 == (i % 16))
    {
      fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
  }

  if (0 != (i % 16))
  {
    fputc('\n', stdout);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char ** tokens;

  {
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...";

    hexdump_chararray(s, sizeof s);

    if (-1 == string_to_tokens(s, ", ", &tokens))
    {
      perror("string_to_tokens() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    print_tokens(tokens);

    hexdump_chararray(s, sizeof s);

    free(tokens);
  }

  {
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...";

    hexdump_chararray(s, sizeof s);

    if (-1 == string_to_tokens_nondistructive(s, ", ", &tokens))
    {
      perror("string_to_tokens_nondistructive() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    print_tokens(tokens);

    hexdump_chararray(s, sizeof s);

    {
      char ** p = tokens;
      while (NULL != *p)
      {
        free(*p);
        ++p;
      }
    }

    free(tokens);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, my approach is to return a NULL-terminated array of pointers to tokens, using `strtok_r` (This code assumes `strdup()` and `strtok_r` are available. Proper headers and all error checking have been omitted for brevity in order to keep the scroll bar from appearing):

```
char **tokenizeString( const char *in, const char *tokens )
{
    char *copy = strdup( in );
    char **array = malloc( sizeof( *array ) );

    // use this for strtok_r(), set to NULL after first use
    char *loopPtr = copy;
    char *savePtr;

    // explicitly break loop when strtok_r()
    // returns NULL (will cause last element
    // of array to be NULL)
    for ( int ii = 0;; ii++ )
    {
        array [ ii ] = strtok_r( loopPtr, tokens, &savePtr );
        if ( !array[ ii ] ) break;
        loopPtr = null; 

        // when ii is zero, we need a two-element array for
        // the next loop iteration
        array = realloc( array, ( ii + 2 ) * sizeof( *tmp ) );
    }
    return( array );
}

void freeTokenizedStringArray( char **array )
{
    free( *array );
    free( array );
}
```

Using `copy` in the loop directly instead of `loopPtr`, and setting `copy` to `NULL` after the call to `strtok_r()` would be even shorter, but in my opinion the use of `loopPtr` makes the intent of the code more apparent.  This is a bit too dense for my tastes:

```
char **tokenizeString( const char *in, const char *tokens )
{
    char *copy = strdup( in );
    char **array = malloc( sizeof( *array ) );
    char *savePtr;

    // explicitly break loop when strtok_r()
    // returns NULL (will cause last element
    // of array to be NULL)
    for ( int ii = 0;; ii++ )
    {
        array [ ii ] = strtok_r( copy, tokens, &savePtr );
        if ( !array[ ii ] ) break;
        copy = null; 

        // when ii is zero, we need a two-element array for
        // the next loop iteration
        array = realloc( array, ( ii + 2 ) * sizeof( *tmp ) );
    }
    return( array );
}
```

In my opinion, that is a bit too reliant upon detailed knowledge of how `strtok_r()` works, something I'd not want to effectively require of some future programmer trying to maintain the code in future years.